# JS - Remove all characters before/after a string (and keep that string)?

Tags: javascript, split, substring

I've seen several results for removing characters after a specific character - my question is how would I do that with a string?

Basically, this applies to any given string of data, but let's take a URL: *stackoverflow.com/question*

With given string, and in JS, I'd like to remove everything after ".com", assign ".com" to a variable, and assign the text before ".com" to a separate variable.

So, end result:  `var x = "stackoverlow" var y = ".com"`

---

What I've done so far:
1) Using a combination of split, substring, etc. I can get it to remove pieces, but not without removing part of the ".com" string. I'm pretty sure I can do what I want to do with substring  and split, I think I'm just implementing it incorrectly.
2) I'm using indexOf to find the string ".com" within the full string

Any tips? I haven't posted my actual code because it's become so garbled with all the different things I've tried (I can go ahead and do so if necessary).

Thanks!

Comment: What if the input is something like `sub.domain.com/something` - do you want the result to be `sub.domain` and `.com`? What if the input includes `.net` rather `.com`?

Comment: Ever heard of [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?

Comment: @nnnnnn The .com was there as a hypothetical - the whole script I'm creating would account for more than just the one suffix.

Comment: @Lenty, then why do you accept an answer that relies on `.com`?

Comment: Because its structure is the closest to what I was looking for :)

Comment: Ah, of course. Who cares about content as long as it's formatted nicely? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really look into Regular Expressions.

Here is some code that can get what you are trying to do:

```
var s = 'stackoverflow.com/question';

var re = /(.+)(\.com)(.+)/;

var result = s.match(re); 

if (result && result.length >= 3) {

    var x = result[1], //"stackoverlow"
        y = result[2]; //".com"

    console.log('x: ' + x);
    console.log('y: ' + y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions.

```
"stackoverflow.com".match(/(.+)(\.com)/)
```

results in

```
["stackoverflow.com", "stackoverflow", ".com"]
```

(Why would you want to assign `.com` to a variable, though?

Comment: Thank you! The .com was more of a hypothetical, used in my question.

Answer (score 0):

`"stackoverflow.com".split(/\b(?=\.)/)` => `["stackoverflow", ".com"]`

Or,

`"stackoverflow.com/question".split(/\b(?=\.)|(?=\/)/)`
=> `["stackoverflow", ".com", "/question"]`